# Install XCode 6 on OSX 10.8.5

Tags: osx-lion, xcode6, xcode4.6, xcode5.1

I have Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5.1.1 installed on my mac with OS X Mountain Lion (10.8.5)

Now I want to install Xcode 6 and keep Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5.1.1 installed.

Is this a good idea or would the old Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5.1.1 interfere with the new version Xcode 6?

Comment: Question is pointless: ["Xcode 6 *requires* a Mac running OS X version 10.9.3 or later."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official [web site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_6_0.html):

> Xcode 6 requires a Mac running OS X version 10.9.4 or later or 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

Install XCode 6 on OSX 10.8.5 not possible.
For manage all xcode installation, You can install all xcode version in your mac, in application folder rename xcode make retain all xcode version without replace it, but xcode comes with compablility of mac os x version so if you want to install xcode 6 you need to update of mac version 10.9.4 or later. Hope so You can understand.